# SSIS - Send Mail Task - Attache multiple newly generated Log files

Tags: sql, ssis, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am executing SSIS package with Batch file execution. At the end it will generate multiple predefined named log files. I want to attache that log files in send mail task.

Log files are located as e.g. (D:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\ABC.log) and (D:\Folder 1\Folder 2\Folder 3\XYZ.log).

I am using following expression in Send Mail Task with File Attachment. **"D:\FOLDER 1\FOLDER 2\FOLDER 3\*.log"** but it doesn't recognize log file.
(There are "2 slashes" in entire path)

Please help me to attach log files.

Comment: have you tried to attach both using a pipe ('|')? `D:\FOLDER 1\FOLDER 2\FOLDER 3\ABC.log|D:\FOLDER 1\FOLDER 2\FOLDER 3\XYZ.log`

Comment: Why the plsqldeveloper tag?

Comment: Yea. If I provide exact file name it works. but my output file name will be different every time. So I want to use *.Log instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating two variables.
    vPath = D:\FOLDER 1\FOLDER 2\FOLDER 3\
    vLogFileMask = *.log
And add these two variables in expressions vPath + vLogFileMask.

Comment: Getting same error: "*.Log" does not exist or you don't have permissions to access the file

Comment: Try to use a send mail task in For Each Loop container. Configure the vLogFileMask in FELC and try integrate it. But here for each file it will trigger a mail. Is this the scenario you are looking for ?